# Why are my images cutted ij lower resolution in horizontal scrolling

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have issue with my imagePreview bar. In lower width resolutions It is cutting my left images and I am unable of see them when i am scrolling to the left. Where could be problem please?

Here is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/relaxed-dewdney-rm4pb?file=/src/App.js

Answer (score 1):

Removing `justify-content` style from the div with class "d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center" should do the trick